# Looping issue - UIMA Ruta

Tags: uima, ruta

**Objective:**

To assign heading levels.

First heading is assigned level 1. I extract font family and size of it and find matching headings. Once the level gets assigned, I unmark the heading, preserving the headings & the features in yet another annotation (HeadingHierarchy). Once the level is finished, I call the same block again and again as long as there is any heading left in Headinglevel annotation.

**Issue:**

The script works fine for finding all level-1 headings. But when the block is executed via Call statement, it finds only the first match for each levels (level 2 onwards). Hence the total number of levels for the below input becomes 10, whereas it has to be 4.

**Input:**(.txt)

```
Apache UIMA Ruta Overview =>Arial,18
What is Apache UIMA Ruta? =>Arial,16
Getting started =>Arial,16
UIMA Analysis Engines =>Arial,16
Ruta Engine =>Times New Roman,14
Configuration Parameters =>Arial,10
Annotation Writer =>Times New Roman,14
Configuration Parameters =>Arial,10
Apache UIMA Ruta Language =>Arial,18
Syntax =>Arial,16
Rule elements and their matching order =>Arial,16
```

**Script:**

```
PACKAGE uima.ruta.example;

DECLARE Headinglevel(STRING family, INT size, INT level);
DECLARE HeadingHierarchy(STRING family, INT size, INT level);
DECLARE FontFamily, FontSize;

STRING family;
INT size;

RETAINTYPE(BREAK);
    BREAK? #{-PARTOF(Headinglevel)} @SPECIAL+ W+ COMMA NUM{->MARK(Headinglevel,2,6), MARK(HeadingHierarchy,2,6), MARK(FontFamily,4), MARK(FontSize,6)};
RETAINTYPE;

h:Headinglevel{->h.family = family, HeadingHierarchy.family = family}
<-{FontFamily{PARSE(family)};};

h:Headinglevel{->h.size = size, HeadingHierarchy.size = size}
<-{FontSize{PARSE(size)};};

INT i=1;

BLOCK(ForEachHeadLevel)Document{}
{
    # h:Headinglevel{-> family = h.family, size = h.size};
    h:Headinglevel{AND(h.family == family, h.size == size)-> h.level=i, HeadingHierarchy.level = i, UNMARK(h)};
}
Headinglevel{->i=i+1, CALL(Test2.ForEachHeadLevel)};
Document{->LOG("    LEVELS : " + (i))};
```

**Expected Output:**

```
   HeadingHierarchy                        Feature

Apache UIMA... =>Arial,18                  level: 1
What is Apa... =>Arial,16                  level: 2
Getting sta... =>Arial,16                  level: 2
UIMA Analys... =>Arial,16                  level: 2
Ruta Engine... =>Times New Roman,14        level: 3
Configurati... =>Arial,10                  level: 4
Annotation ... =>Times New Roman,14        level: 3
Configurati... =>Arial,10                  level: 4
Apache UIMA... =>Arial,18                  level: 1
Syntax =>Ar... =>Arial,16                  level: 2
Rule elemen... =>Arial,16                  level: 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the CALL restricts the window on the span matched by the rule element. This means that the BLOCK is only executed within an existing Headinglevel annotation. However, you need to have the complete document so that the second rule in the block does its job.

This is most likely not the best solution, but the first one that came to my mind.

You could reset the window within the BLOCK to the complete document regardless of the restriction of the CALL action with DOCUMENTBLOCK:

```
BLOCK (ForEachHeadLevel)Document{}
{
    DOCUMENTBLOCK Document{} 
    {
        # h:Headinglevel{-> family = h.family, size = h.size};
        h:Headinglevel{AND(h.family == family, h.size == size)-> h.level=i, HeadingHierarchy.level = i, UNMARK(h)};
    }
}
```

`DOCUMENTBLOCK` is a block extension. You need to include `org.apache.uima.ruta.block.DocumentBlockExtension` in the `additionalExtensions` configuration parameter.

Here's another solution using a FOREACH block:

```
INT i=0;
FOREACH(hl) Headinglevel{}{
    hl{IS(Headinglevel)-> i=i+1, family = hl.family, size = hl.size};
    h:Headinglevel{h.family == family, h.size == size ->  h.level=i, HeadingHierarchy.level = i, UNMARK(h)};
}
```

*DISCLAIMER: I am a developer of UIMA Ruta*

Comment: I added org.apache.uima.ruta.block.DocumentBlockExtension in the additionalExtensions. But I get the error, Type "DOCUMENTBLOCK " not defined in this script/block!

Comment: Looks like the newly added parameter gets removed once the script is run (with errors in this case). The same happens with dictRemoveWS and so will have to add it every time we run the script.

Comment: Yes, it looks as the extension is not available in the Workbench. I will fix it.

Comment: Yes, there are many ways. I assume you could also do it with a single rule with a list storing the observed layouts, if you make all but Headings invisible.I added another way with a FOREACH block (mind that this block is slower as it should be in 2.5.0)

Comment: "I assume you could also do it with a single rule with a list storing the observed layouts, if you make all but Headings invisible."  - Can you plz elaborate it ?

Comment: About the parameters: you can change the default values of the generated  descriptors by modifying the template. For simple ruta project, this is descriptor/Basicengine.xml. For maven projects, you can specify the template in the configuration of the ruta-maven-plugin.

Comment: The comment about "make all but Headings invisible" refers to a situation where you need sequential matching between Headinglevel annotations in case they are separated by content. Not necessary in the previous exemplary rules.

Comment: Checked my comment about the single rule again. Unfortunately, it is not as easy as I thought to specify the logic using only one rule. Its probably possible, but would take quite some time to specify that rule. I'd rather stick with one of the exmaples given in the answer.